# Using Breadth-First Search to find the shortest path in a maze

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search

I have a coding problem in which I am supposed to find the shortest path for a robot to go in a maze from a given starting point to an end point. The format of the input is as follows:
Two numbers (R, C) on the first line of input, which give the number of rows and columns in the maze, followed by R lines of input, each consisting of C characters. The maze has a starting point labelled as S and an end point labelled as E. A hash (#) stands for a wall in the maze and a dot (.) stands for a free square in the maze. So a sample input looks like this:

```
6 5
S....
.#...
..E..
.....
#....
#...#
```

The robot can move in all four directions and the required output is to write the directions for the robot to follow that would lead him from S to E in the shortest path. I am thinking of using a standard Breadth-First Search for it. However, there is this condition that once the robot starts moving in one direction, it cannot stop until it hits a wall (#) or reaches one end of the maze. Using a standard Breadh-First Search would allow me to find the shortest path but it does not take into account this condition. Can you suggest how to modify the algorithm to work, please?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the shortest path the shortest distance or the minimal number of order gave to the robot?

Comment: When you check for neighbors of the current position, rather than the neighbor being the grid point directly to the right (for example), it will be the grid point that is *furthest* to the right before reaching an obstacle. So from `S`, its right neighbor will not be the grid point (0,1), but (0,4).

Comment: @TUIlover It's the minimum number of orders given to the robot. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @latka-krystof then beaker already have answered your question: you just have to change the definition of a neighbor in your algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## In case you want to minimize the distance:

All you have to do is to add an extra boolean to the coordinates that states whether the direction is vertical or not. The boolean can be changed if and only if it hits a wall or one end of the maze (making the path to split into two). It is at this moment that you must push on a stack associated to each path the choice of direction.

If you store the already encountered nodes with the boolean, it will allow paths to cross but never repeat. With breadth first algorithm, you'll find the shortest path when first encountering the end. The stack associated to the path is the result you search for.

## In case you want to minimize orders number

You have to change the way you define a neighbor in your algorithm : for all four directions you try to go as far as possible and stop when it reach a limit. The neighbor for each direction is the last cell you’ve reached. If the last cell have already been visited, it is not valid.